# Shopify keeps erasing applied_discount

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I'm using the REST API to try to create a draft order with a single line-item that is 100% discounted.

```
{
  draft_order: {
    customer: customer,
    note: "this is my note",
    line_items: [
      {
        variant_id: 8935893599248,
        quantity: 1,
        applied_discount: {
          title: 'FREE',
          description: 'FREE Item',
          value_type: 'percentage',
          value: '0.00',
          amount: '0.00',
        }
      }
    ],
    shipping_address: {
      address1: data[:address_1],
      address2: data[:address_2],
      city: data[:city],
      province: data[:state],
      zip: data[:zip_code],
      country_code: data[:country],
      phone: data[:phone]
    }.compact
  }
}
```

It creates the draft order, but in the response it keeps erasing the discount it and setting it to `nil`... it is driving me insane. I've tried every combination I can think of. So insanely frustrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to update the json format if you want to create a draft order for 100% discount you just need to assign value as 100 and amount should be the price of product for which you want to give discount

Here 123456789 is my product's variant id 
and price of my product is 99.00,
 Some of data is not as per your data so only change data , but format must be same

Here I mentioned customer id , you can skip this index if you want to apply discount for all of your customer , order specify the id or email for any particular customer but format must be same.

```
{
  "draft_order": {
    "note":"this is my note",
    "line_items": [
      {
        "variant_id": 123456789,
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ],
    "applied_discount": {
      "title": "FREE",
      "description": "FREE Item",
      "value": "100",
      "value_type": "percentage",
      "amount": "99"
    },
    "customer": {
      "id": 987456321
    },
    "shipping_address": {
      "address1": "123 Amoebobacterieae St",
      "address2": "",
      "city": "Ottawa",
      "company": null,
      "country": "Canada",
      "first_name": "Bob",
      "last_name": "Bobsen",
      "latitude": "45.41634",
      "longitude": "-75.6868",
      "phone": "555-625-1199",
      "province": "Ontario",
      "zip": "K2P0V6",
      "name": "Bob Bobsen",
      "country_code": "CA",
      "province_code": "ON"
    }
  }
}
```

You can take reference from here https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/orders/draftorder#create-2019-07

Comment: If you face any issue please let me know

Comment: Awesome thank you @ankit -- i will look at this later today and ill let you know if i have any Q, then i'll mark it as the answer :)

Comment: is it possible to do the discount without knowing the price of the product first? that is a whole extra API call

Comment: I think when you fetch the variant Id ,on that call you can easily know the price of product,but if you saved only variant Id anywhere ,in that case you should call shopify variant api,but for your case I will do research on that, thank you:)